# How to use word2vec?

Tags: java, word2vec

I have to make lexical graph with words within a corpus. For that, I need to make a program with word2vec.

The thing is that I'm new at this. I've tried for 4 days now to find a way to use word2vec but I'm lost. My big problem is that I don't even know where to find the code in Java (I heard about deeplearning but I couldn't find the files on their website), how to integrate it in my project...

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way to embody the *Word2Vec* representation in your java code is to use *deeplearning4j*, the one you have mentioned. I assume you have already seen the main pages of the project. For what concerns the code, check these links:

- [Github repository](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j)
- [Examples](https://github.com/SkymindIO/dl4j-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/word2vec)